# Integration: Area between curves

Tags: integration

Let $f(x)=x^2−c^2$ and $g(x)=c^2−x^2.$ Find $c>0$ such that the area of the region enclosed by the parabolas $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ is 9.

The question above is what I am having trouble with. In order to solve this problem I use the formula given as:

$\int_a^b f(x) - g(x) dx$

Here is what I have done so far:

$9 = \int x^2−c^2 - (c^2−x^2) dx$

$9 = \int 2x^2−2c^2 dx$

$9 = 2\int x^2−c^2 dx$

$\frac 9 2 = \int x^2−c^2 dx$

To find a and b:

$x^2 - c^2 = (x-c)(x+c)$ ; therefore  $a = -c$ and $b = c$

Back to the original question, sub in a and b:

$\frac 9 2 = \int_{-c}^c x^2−c^2 dx$

This is as far as I have gotten. I am not sure what to do next. Thanks in advance to anyone who can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Draw a picture. I would use *symmetry* and say that the area is $4$ times the integral from $0$ to $c$ of $c^2-x^2$. So we want
$$\int_0^c (c^2-x^2)\,dx=\frac{9}{4}.$$
The integral is equal to $\frac{2}{3}c^3$. Now solve for $c$.

**Remark:** Your approach will work, except that we want $\int_{-c}^c (c^2-x^2)\,dx=\frac{9}{2}$. Note that $\int_{-c}^c (x^2-c^2)\,dx$ is negative.

Comment: This may be trivial, but how do you get ∫c−c(c^2−x^2)dx=9/2 ?

Comment: The region is symmetrical about the $x$-axis. The "top" curve is $y=c^2-x^2$. We want the area below the top curve and above the $x$-axis to be $\frac{9}{2}$. The area of the region below $y=c^2-x^2$, above the $x$-axis, from $x=-c$ to $x=c$ is precisely the integral mentioned in the remark.

Comment: The only mistake you made is that you should have worked with $(c^2-x^2)-(x^2-c^2)$ (top curve minus bottom curve) and instead you reversed them.